# How to have a function with multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql

i have an issue that i am stumped with.  I am trying to add data to different tables based on a different field value, and I am having issues with the code when I try adding multiple instances for each value.

The code I am using is:

```
$data = array();
$data["Division"] = "Novice A";
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );
```

If i just have that single instance, then it works properly, but I tried using the following code below, and every time an entry was added, it was added to every table, so I am not sure how to make it work.

```
$data = array();
$data["Division"] = "Novice A";
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );

$data = array();
$data["Division"] = "Novice B";
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - B", $data );

$data = array();
$data["Division"] = "Starter A";
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - A", $data );
```

I tried to use If then statements,  but i kept receiving errors, can someone please help guide me, since i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is the complete set of code that I am using:

```
function BeforeAdd($values, $message, $inline, $PageObject)
{
// Insert records into Division tables //

if($data["Division"] = 'Training'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Training", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Novice A'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Novice B'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'BN A'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("BN - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'BN B'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("BN - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter A'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter B'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter C'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - C", $data );

} 

return true;
```

As I stated before, when I try to add a record with any of those division names in the field, for some reason, it's only placing them in the first listed table, and not sure why, or how to fix it.

Comment: how is this related to javascript?

Comment: normally you can add `unset($data)` to clear the array before you do the next step to fix such issue

Comment: So I looked and tried the elseif statement with the following code, which worked for a few tests, but now when I add a record, no matter what the "Division" field contains, it gets added to the table in the first, so am I missing something

Comment: 'if($data["Division"] = "Training"){'
$data = array();'
'$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];'
'$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];'
'$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];'

'DB::Insert("Training", $data );'

'} elseif($data["Division"] = "Novice A"){'
'$data = array();'
'$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];'
'$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];'
'$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];'
'DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );'
'}'

Comment: So would I add that code above every `$data = array();` ? @KenLee

Comment: @KenLee - I tried the `unset($data)` above the `$data = array();` and tried replacing `$data = array();` with `unset($data)` so the records look like this:
`unset($data)`
`$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];`
`$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];`
`$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];`
`$data["Division"] = "Novice A";`
``
`DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );`
`}` and then the record was added to every table

Comment: It seems no error in this code section, can you show us whole code how you are implementing

Comment: @VirenderKumar I will post the entire code above in my original question.  So, when I run the syntax checker for the code there are no errors, but when I try to add a record, it only goes into the table of the first set of code.

Comment: @dmcomp according to your function it will go to first if condition because you are assigning the variable in if simply, replace the simple = sign to == like this if($data["Division"] == 'Training') but after doing this comparison operator, it will not insert any record and will return true actually. because there is no $data variable in function. How are you getting this $data in this function? Still something is missing and one more thing are you using some library to DB::insert or what framework you are using here

Comment: @VirenderKumar - Oops I just realized that it didn't show that I did put == but after i did that, it inserts all records into the second array "Novice - A" table.  I am using phprunner and that array script is a predefined code base, and I just tried modifying it to fit my needs.

Comment: @dmcomp My first question is from where you are getting $data variable it is not available in your given function and second is to update = to == in all if and elseif conditions if you want to use if else condition after that give me the feedback  what happens

Comment: @VirenderKumar - I tried that before, and when I added == to every set, then it didnt insert the record into any table.  If this is not the way to do it, what code should I be using to accomplish this?

Comment: @VirenderKumar - this is the example they give on the phprunner website:  ``` Example 2. Database API

 

//**********  Insert a record into another table  ************
$data = array();
$data["make"] = "Toyota";
$data["model"]  = "RAV4";
$data["price"] = 16000;
DB::Insert("cars", $data ); ```

Comment: @VirenderKumar - so at first I used that example and created multiple arrays, but then it would add you every table

Comment: @dmcomp In your question you are saying "trying to add data to different tables based on a different field value". Where are different values? 
Only Division has different values and others like Number, Rider name and Horse Name are same for all. So it is inserting all values same in all tables and only division value will be different in your tables.

Comment: @dmcomp Based on your code you are inserting static data to your database for all tables and there is no benefit of if else condition in your case. You should print these params ($values, $message, $inline, $PageObject ) values first which are coming through function and see what is coming and try to add screenshot of those values for better understanding and implementation here. Basically concept is not clear why, how and what you want to add in different tables.